# HTML - padding-left but keep text centered

Tags: html, css, layout, styles

I have following HTML and CSS:

```css
#page {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  height: 360px;
  width: 360px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#viewport {
  font-size: 20pt;
  text-align: center;
}

.taskTitle {
  height: 13%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30pt;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.taskNote {
  color: gray;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="viewport">
    <div id="task-view">

      <div style="width: 100%; background-color: aqua; position: relative;">
        <img style="background-color: blue; position: absolute; left :0%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-0%, -50%);" src="./image/tw_btn_radio_holo_dark.png"></img>
        <div style="width: 100%; background-color: red;">
          <div class="taskTitle" id="taskTitle1" style="background-color: green; width: 100%">Long text overlays picture :(</div>
          <div class="taskNote" id="taskNote1">My Note 1</div>
        </div>

      </div>


      <div style="width: 100%; background-color: orange; position: relative;">
        <img style="background-color: blue; position: absolute; left :0%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-0%, -50%);" src="./image/tw_btn_radio_holo_dark.png"></img>
        <div style="width: 100%; background-color: red;">
          <div style="background-color: green;" class="taskTitle" id="taskTitle2">Short</div>
          <div class="taskNote" id="taskNote2">Short text should always centerd in page!</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would have the followed:

- Display the pciture always at the left side of the screen
- Display the picture always in the vertical-center of the parent div
- Center Text (Title and Note) always at the center of the **screen**
- Text should not overlay the picture

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set `z-index:100;` for the picture, and for the text `z-index:50;`
So it doesent overlay.

For centering use `<center></center>`or `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;`

For holding the picture on the left side: `left:0;` or `float:left;`

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

You can use this for your text overflowing the image:

```
.taskTitle {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And on your taskNote `class` as well. You are going to handle the `font-size` if you want it to fit its parent container.

For more about `alignment` and `positioning` in `CSS`, see this [article](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) written by Chris Coyier at: [CSS-Tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/)

Try to break down your different questions a bit and if you still have troubles ask them separately by priority. Good luck!